# Length of groupby result in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

### Problem

I want to calculate the **number of unique combinations of two columns**. What is the most performant way to achieve this using pandas?

For me, the most intuitive way is to groupby the columns and take the length of the object. However, for a large dataframe, I find the performance to be about 5x slower than the second variant below.

```py
# Quick
len1 = lambda: len(df[['a', 'b']].groupby(['a', 'b'], observed=True).nunique())
# Slow
len2 = lambda: len(df[['a', 'b']].groupby(['a', 'b'], observed=True))
```

### Questions

1. Why is the second variant faster?
2. What is the **fastest** way for this calculation?

### MWE to reproduce

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit

# Set the number of rows and columns
num_rows = 10000000
num_cols = 5

# Generate random numbers
data = np.random.rand(num_rows, num_cols)

# Convert columns a and b to categorical values
data[:, 0] = pd.Categorical(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=num_rows))
data[:, 1] = pd.Categorical(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=num_rows))

# Create a DataFrame with the random numbers and categorical values
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

len1 = lambda: len(df[['a', 'b']].groupby(['a', 'b'], observed=True).nunique())
len2 = lambda: len(df[['a', 'b']].groupby(['a', 'b'], observed=True))
           
time1 = timeit.timeit(len1, number=10)
print(f"Execution time of len1: {time1:.5f} seconds")

time2 = timeit.timeit(len2, number=10)
print(f"Execution time of len2: {time2:.5f} seconds")
```

Output:

```bash
Execution time of len1: 3.16599 seconds
Execution time of len2: 17.47438 seconds
```

Comment: Do you need test 100 groups? Because `np.random.randint(0, 10, size=num_rows)` in your solution return only 10 unique values. Maybe need `np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=num_rows)` ?

Comment: The number of groups is not essential for me understanding the problem. I chose the number arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `groupby` that is slow, I would use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df[['a', 'b']].drop_duplicates().shape[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `sum` with inverted mask:

```
out = (~df[['a', 'b']].duplicated()).sum()
```

Or use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
out = np.unique(df[['a', 'b']].to_numpy(), axis=0).shape[0]
```